# "Introduce person to object" or "introduce object to person"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, word-order

> - I'd like to introduce you to this technology.
> - I'd like to introduce this tech to you.

Which one is right and what are appropriate uses?

Comment: @tchrist: I think ["{he} introduced me to heroin"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduced+me+to+heroin%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is a slightly tongue-in-cheek way of phrasing things. We normally only use this form with an inanimate object if there's something "quirky" or otherwise unusual about either the thing being introduced, or the nature of the subsequent relationship that develops after the introduction.

Comment: Why would either be wrong or better to use?

Comment: @Matt: Per my answer, both are "wrong" to me because *I'd like to introduce X to Y* is effectively a "set phrase" used when formally presenting person X to higher-status person Y. But the first version is even more wrong, since it implies *you have lower status* than the technology.

Comment: "I'm going to show you blat," or "I'm going to present blat to you."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the conventional phrasing is, "I'd like to introduce you to this new technology." You can debate the significance of saying it either way, but I think that's how most people say it.

Comment: You can also [*introduce a new product to the market*.](http://www.ehow.com/how_4813351_introduce-new-product-market.html), though not ordinarily to an individual. [From the free dictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/introduce) 4b. To bring into currency, use, or practice; originate: introduced the new product in several test markets; introduced the tango into their circle of friends.

Answer (score 1):

From [etymonline's](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=introduction) entry for **introduction**...

> The sense of "formal presentation of one person to another" is from 1711.

Obviously there are lots of other usages - you can [introduce another variable into [an equation]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduce%20another%20variable%20into%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), or [introduce a bill [to Parliament/to ban unicorn hunting/etc.]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduce%20another%20variable%20into%20the%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22introduce%20a%20bill%20to%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=D31rUKyZM8vIsga1qYCwBA&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=843), for example.

But I would find both *"Let me introduce **you to [thing]**"* and *"Let me introduce **[thing] to you**"* equally incorrect/insulting in most contexts. All such usages are based on the definition above, which implies *two people meeting and acknowledging each other*.

Standard etiquette is you introduce the lower-status person to the one with higher status, but using this form with inanimate objects is usually facetious, mock-ceremonial, or outright sarcastic/rude.

---

There are obviously differences of opinion here, and I may in the minority in seeing an element of disrespect when someone offers to *introduce me to [something]* (or indeed, the other way around).

But as to the matter of low/high status, I would just note that Google Books claims over 31,000 hits for ["introduced **him to the king**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduced%20the%20king%20to%20him%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22introduced%20him%20to%20the%20king%22&oq=%22introduced%20him%20to%20the%20king%22&gs_l=serp.3...5275.9610.1.10107.14.14.0.0.0.2.207.1204.10j3j1.14.0...0.0...1c.1.xzE-uCuXHtw&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886), but not a single instance of ["introduced **the king to him**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduced%20the%20king%20to%20him%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

As to OP's specific question, note that GB claims 4520 hits for ["introduced **him to the concept**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduce%20the%20president%20to%20him%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22introduced%20him%20to%20the%20concept%22&oq=%22introduced%20him%20to%20the%20concept%22&gs_l=serp.3...4572.9187.2.9699.14.14.0.0.0.0.58.685.14.14.0...0.0...1c.1.SbbpXeaMywo&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886), but only 5 for ["introduced **the concept to him**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduce%20the%20president%20to%20him%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22introduced%20the%20concept%20to%20him%22&oq=%22introduced%20the%20concept%20to%20him%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.3.127983.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.pMweALKLcMg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e15cb1ee18b97dae&biw=1304&bih=886). Whether or not you perceive any "slight" in this usage, the person is invariably introduced to the abstract concept, not the other way around.

Comment: +1 for getting past the either/or and interjecting "why"?

Comment: -1 you can introduce things to people. It is normal, not necessarily any of the things you suggest. See [introduce something to](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/introduce?q=introduce).

Comment: @Matt: Imho, the example *the programme is a bid to introduce opera to the masses* in your link is either "mock-ceremonial" as referenced above, or it's just the "literal" sense as per [Cane toads were introduced to Australia from Hawaii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cane_toads_in_Australia). Notwithstanding that, you'll often see ["introduced **him to drugs**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduced+him+to+drugs%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but not ["introduced **drugs to him**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduced+drugs+to+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: I agree with your second point, but not your first.

Comment: I think I get it now. Some people might be offended when introduced to things, others might not, as they don't see anything humiliating or disrespectful in such phrasing. I guess most researchers and people of science belong to the latter group.

Comment: @user1306322: I've no doubt most non-facetious instances of *"I'd like to introduce you to [thing]"* aren't consciously intended to be disrespectful. The speaker is usually just trying to elevate the status of "thing" (by "personifying" it and presenting you before it). I suppose you could also read your usage as a form of *"I'd like to **introduce you into** the metaphorical space represented by this technology and those who already use it"* - but again, to me the unspoken implication is ***you*** are unimportant/ignorant, and in need of enlightenment.

Comment: Maybe this is one of those UK/US things. Yes, I've read in etiquette books that you introduce the lower status person to the higher status. But I think few Americans have heard this rule and fewer still think about it when making introductions. I have never, ever heard an American indicate that he was insulted or otherwise thought anything was inappropriate because the order of the persons named in an introduction was wrong. I have often heard people say "We want to introduce people to this new technology" and variations thereof, and I've never heard anyone question this on etiquette grounds.

Comment: @Jay: I don't think the "status" issue is a UK/US distinction. I just used *King* in the answer, and *Queen* in my comment, because I'm a Brit, so they're natural to me. But GB claims over 6000 instances of ["introduce him to the president"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduce+him+to+the+president%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) against only one for ["introduce the president to him"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22introduce+the+president+to+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so clearly ***that*** distinction applies both sides of the pond.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This might make an interesting topic of itself. I'd say, (a) Among the few places where America does have elaborate rules of etiquette is in our Federal government and sometimes in top business circles. So if such rules EVER appliedin the US, it would be in connection with the president. (b) I think the conventional rule in America is that you talk about introducting the person who is close to the person who is far away. That is, if I'm telling Sally the secretary that she will now be working for Fred the big boss, I'll say "Sally, I'll introduce you to your new boss, Fred." ...

Comment: ... But if I'm telling Fred that we've gotten him a new secretary, I say "Fred, I'll introduce you to your new secretary, Sally." I can't imagine saying "Fred, I'll introduce your new secretary, Sally, to you" because Fred is higher status. In connection with the president, it's much more likely that we're talking to or about someone other than the president, and saying we'll intro him to the pres. So I'd expect "intro him to the pres" to show up more than the reverse. ...

Comment: ... If I was talking to the president, I'm sure I would say, "Hey Barack, I'll introduce you to the new janitor" without a moment's hesitation. (c) The original point was about people taking the phrasing as insulting. Regardless of any rules of etiquette, I can't imagine that if I said to my boss, "Fred, let me introduce you to your new secretary" that he would be offended or insulted.

Comment: @Jay: That's a lot to write without meaningfully addressing the 6000:1 preference in Google Books for underlings to be introduced to presidents, not the other way around. I accept that many people may be simply unaware of the implications of their words - I'm sure most people who call someone else a [berk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/berk) would be horrified if they knew how *some* people understand the term. So maybe I'm a just bit of a "sensitive soul" and the first half of my answer is somewhat OTT, but the "precedence" stuff seems to me rock-solid.

Comment: Google finds plenty of instances of "introduce the president to ..." Like http://southlanddemocrats.com/index.html "introduce the president to a packed house", http://www.banksterusa.org/content/bush-tax-cuts-need-expire-pay-bushs-spending "introduce the president to my family", http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/mrs-kennedy-barbara-leaming/1004784999 "introduce the president to LSD" (?), http://www.reagan.utexas.edu/archives/speeches/1982/51882d.htm "introduce the president to you" (referring to members of some commission), etc.

Comment: @Jay: Googling the entire Internet will find plenty of instances of just about anything, but one might suppose that what makes it into "print" (i.e. - Google ***Books***) has higher credibility when it comes to "proper" usage. Whatever - even on the Internet at large, I've no doubt *"introduced [lesser person] to the president"* massively outnumbers *"introduced the president to [lesser person]"*. And with *lesser person = **him*** even the mighty Google only manages to find 5 instances, against an estimated 4M hits for the other way around.

Comment: –1: While I have heard of this formal introduction stuff, it's almost entirely alien to me, and I would honestly have no clue whether I was being honored or insulted by somebody who did know the rules. I don't think that reasoning is suitable without a strong disclaimer about its applicability with regard to region, class, context, etc. In particular, I don't think it makes much sense to apply it to an _informal_ sense of “introduction.”

Comment: I can’t find any social distinctions in introductions, either. I would base the order on length and familiarity of the objects: “When next I looked, he was introducing her to the president”, but not, “… he was introducing the former Tory representative of the Newcastle-upon-Tyne social welfare committee to him [the president]”—that is much more awkward than the other way around. Pronouns are the shortest and most familiar objects possible, therefore they will always come first, regardless of social status: “She introduced him [the president] to her mayor”, for example.

Comment: @Brad,Janus: The idea of etiquette/priority seems logical to me. OED defines *introduce* as *To lead or bring in (a person or thing) into a place, position, state, condition, or relation to something*. In the case of *social* introductions (and OP's context, which I understand to be a slightly whimsical version thereof) it seems to me it's effectively equivalent to ***present***. [This site says](http://www.etiquetteinternational.com/Articles/Introductions.aspx) *persons of lesser authority are introduced to persons of greater authority* (unless ladies "outrank" men by reason of chivalry).

Comment: Etiquette and priority certainly make sense – I just don't think “introduce” carries that kind of weight in the places I've lived.

Comment: @Bradd: Well, I did say *I may in the minority*, and I do recognise that not everyone would see things from my point of view. Strictly speaking it wouldn't make a lot of sense for me to feel "slighted" by someone offering to *introduce me* to some new software or hardware, if they had no idea how their choice of words might be interpreted. I'd almost certainly *notice* it, but in reality I'd probably just think the guy was a bit careless and/or ignorant, rather than intentionally rude.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally say “I’d like to introduce this technology to you”.

Reversing an introduction could possibly give offense, or create confusion, but many people would never notice the difference. In any case, it would not be in any way ungrammatical.

The meaning of *introduce* is to “[b]ring a subject to the attention of (someone) for the first time”. (*Google Dictionary*) This is consistent with the history of the word: *introduce* was borrowed from a Latin verb with the sense of “to lead (or bring) in”, so literally to bring a subject to someone. (*Online Etymology Dictionary*)

Because you are bringing the technology to a person’s attention, then, the conventional direction of the introduction is “to you”.

The word has also long been used to mean a formal presentation of one person to another; again, the common meaning is “to lead (or bring) in”, and in the case of a formal presentation this may literally mean to bring a person to someone. It has correctly been pointed out in other answers and comments that the social custom is that a subordinate will be introduced to (led to) a superior, not the other way around. In a situation of equality, one social formula is “introduce you to one another”.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some politically correct answer, but I'd say that you should introduce the one you know less well to the one you know better. Either one is fine is with me, and I won't be offended (i.e., I won't choose to take offense) no matter which way the introduction goes. But this is a question for Miss Manners, not for ELU.

Comment: Interesting take. But I think it's not so much a matter of which *you know best* - more a matter of which one *has the higher status*. So you'd *introduce [a pleb] to the Queen*, rather than the other way around. In OP's case I'd simply avoid using the word *introduce* altogether, since it seems potentially insulting either way round. Far more appropriate would be something like *"I'd like you to have a look at this technology"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How is it insulting, and to whom? I guess I'm often a step behind on political correctness, but I can't say I've ever been offended when someone said, "Here, let me introduce you to the new printer" or whatever.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Now that you mention it, I do remember something about introducing younger people to older, underlings to bosses, and lower status people to higher. But because I'm a working class social egalitarian, I keep forgetting who is who. And sometimes the technology is more important than the person, which anyone who has a teenaged kid knows.

Comment: Noting particularly @Jay's position here, I think I'll have to post an alternative answer...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think there may be more than a "semantic" difference between _introducing_ new technology to someone and _presenting_ someone to, say, the Queen. I could be wrong about that: the thesaurus shows them as about 75-90% synonymous. But tourists generally are said to _introduce_ (but **not** to _present_) dangerous new species when they dump their wild overseas pets into the local rivers. Ergo, _introducing_ is bringing something new into someone else's world. Still, maybe _Let me **show** you this new technology_ is better here. "An alternative answer" is a good idea.

Comment: @Bill: Well, I didn't downvote your answer - but I didn't upvote it either. And looking at these examples of [to introduce you to this new...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to+introduce+you+to+this+new%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *(...kind of personal achievement plan?!)*, I can't say I agree with Jay's answer either. We'll have to give it a few weeks to see how the votes go, but I do think it's an interesting question, and your answer remains an "interesting take" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I didn't think you'd downvoted the answer, but because it's not standard, I grok the downvote. No big deal. What's important is maintaining the quality of one's answers so that others can learn something they can use (I learn a lot here every day, & not just about English), not worrying about gaining or losing points. I make mistakes, just like everyone else. There are always consequences. OTOH, I've obviously made a few enemies here (I don't play well in groups), so I expect random spitballs & have an idea or two about where they come from. Reality's not personal, just there.

Comment: @tchrist Not sure if you're just being facetious or think this is really an issue. Yes, of course no one is going to follow-up "Let me introduce you to the new printer" with "Sam the Printer, meet my friend Bob." But that's the nature of language, isn't it, that the same words can be applied in different situations with different shades of meaning? Just like I might say "the dishwasher is running". I wouldn't follow that with "... and I'd better catch it before it gets too far away", except as a joke.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Longman English Dictionary Online](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/introduce), both are fine:

> 4. New experience: to show someone something or tell them about it for the first time 
>    introduce somebody to something/introduce something to
>      somebody
>    Example: *Malcolm introduced me to
>      the joys of wine-tasting.*